# TLS 1.0 for certain URLs in an Azure Web App

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, tls1.2

Can I allow TLS 1.0 for certain URLs in an Azure Web App?
A minimum version of TLS 1.2 works for >99% of my site but a few URL's are used by legacy clients that don't support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full URL (i.e. domain and path) requested by the client is only known to the server after the TLS handshake is completed since it is only sent in the HTTP request inside the established TLS connection. But, if a TLS protocol version is acceptable or not must be known before the TLS handshake can be completed. Thus, the decision which TLS protocol version is acceptable cannot be done based on the full URL.

Answer (score 0):

In Web Apps, you're selecting TLS level on a per-app basis, all settings under that app are included.